# How to check if all or any element in a groovy list meet a condition

Tags: arrays, list, groovy

I have an array or list, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, say. How do I check that `ALL or ANY` of the elements in this list meet a given condition? For example, how do I check that `ALL` these elements are greater than 0 or `ANY` element is a multiple of 5?

Answer (score 4):

To check that ALL elements in a list meet a given condition;

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

if(myList.every{ it > 0 }){
    println('all good!')
}
```

To check that ANY elements in a list meet a given condition, say multiple of 5;

```
 if(myList.any{ it % 5 == 0 }){
        println('contains at least 1 multiple of 5!')
 }
```